# PHP, crontab, DateInterval: Convert human-readable interval to crontab format

Tags: php, linux, datetime, cron, intervals

I'm having a little confusion with crontab interval format. The point is that i want to get intervals from human-readable strings like "20 minutes", "16 hours and 30 minutes". This is done by [PHP DateTime already](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php). But what I need is passing crontab-valid string as `exec(sprintf('echo "%s %s %s * * %s" | crontab', $minute, $hour, $day, $command));`. Anyhow, here is sample PHP script

```
<?php
function getCrontabInterval($timestring)
{
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($timestring);

    $minute = $interval->i > 0 ? "*/{$interval->i}" : '*';
    $hour = $interval->h > 0 ? "*/{$interval->h}" : '*';
    $day = $interval->d > 0 ? "*/{$interval->d}" : '*';
    $crontab = sprintf('echo "%s %s %s * * %s" | crontab', $minute, $hour, $day, '%command%');

    echo "Days:\t\t", $interval->d, "\n",
        "Hours:\t\t", $interval->h, "\n",
        "Minutes:\t", $interval->i, "\n",
        "COMMAND:\t", $crontab, "\n";
}


 getCrontabInterval($_SERVER['argv'][1]);
```

And its output:

```
serge@serge-laptop:~/www/bin$ php periodical.php '2 hours 25 minutes'
Days:       0
Hours:      2
Minutes:    25
COMMAND:    echo "*/25 */2 * * * %command%" | crontab
```

So, will the "*/25 */2 * * *" cron value match running command EACH 2 hours 25 minutes? Or it should be something like "0/25 0/2 * * *"? It was not clear for me from manpages. And how to act with days?

UPD: Under each "2 hours 25 minutes" i mean running at 0:00, 2:25, 4:50, 7:15 and etc

SOLUTION:
used two-component value for intervals with some manual recommendation to use values like 20 minutes, 3 hours, 4 days and etc.

Comment: Are you trying to run every 2h and 25 minutes? Or 25 minutes after every 2 hours?

Comment: I mean 0:00, 2:25, 4:50, 7:15 and etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*/25 */2 * * *` means at 0:00, 0:25, 0:50, 2:00, 2:25, 2:50, 4:00, 4:25, 4:50 etc...

`25 */2 * * *` means 0:25, 2:25, 4:25, 6:25, etc...

`0/25 0/2 * * *` means 0:25 only

**EDIT** - After your update

To my knowledge there is no way to do it with a single line in a crontab. The mechanism for specifying at what time your cron job runs is not meant for this kind of complexity.
You can however have 9 or 10 entries in your crontab with different times to the same script if you really need that 2h25 functionality

Comment: will revise this option. i think i'll reduce everything to "25 minutes" -> "*/25 * * * * *", "2 hours" -> "* */2 * * *" (or 0 */2 * * *?...), "3 days" -> "* * */3 * *"

Answer (score 1):

String "*/25 */2 * * *" will runs command each 2 hours EACH 25 minutes
String "25 */2 * * *" will runs command each 2 hours 25 minutes